# Network manager slow to connect

Tags: network-manager

On Kubuntu 20.04 the NetworkManager is slow to connect via LAN. It is in the "Setting network address" state for about 20-30 seconds, while dhclient from console connects (obtains IP) immediately. I'm not sure what other info to include, which log files etc. to post to help resolve this. Please advice.

More info as reaction to the comments:
1) this happens even when using a single connection.
2) I'm not sure what is "Plasma KDE network manager" what I'm trying to use comes from the network-manager package.

Comment: I had the similar problem with network manager of KDE plasma. Now when I encounter it I first disconnect and then reconnect and All done !  I don't know what the problem is , but you can [report the bug](https://bugs.kde.org/).

Comment: This problem only happens when I want to connect to a network while I'm using another one . Is your situation similar ?

Comment: in Connections -> Connect automatically with priority -> set to 99, maybe this will help you to establish the connection faster